# How to place <input type="file"> inside <input type="text"> tag?

Tags: php, forms

My question is When user selects a file the file name should appear on the text field. please tell me how do this??

Comment: <input type="file" onchange="this.form.file_name.value = this.value">

Comment: An input inside another won't work. For security reasons, file inputs cannot display a "default" value set prior to the file selection. You need to think out of the box and use JS to "fake" the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your HTML

```
<input type="file" id = "file_upload" />
<input id="file_name" type="text" />
```

your javascript

```
document.getElementById('file_upload').onchange = file_name;

function file_name() {
    var filename = this.value;
    var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
    if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
    }
    document.getElementById('file_name').value = filename;
}
```